# Getting Data From stdClass Object From Facebook API with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am trying to get values from a `stdClass Object` holding Facebook data.

My goal is to save the data to a database. So I am trying to isolate the information in the array with no luck.

I am requesting the data like this,

```
$graphObject = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,tagged_places' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Please notice I am requesting multiple fields. `first_name last_name` and `tagged_places`

I am then printing the data to my screen like this,

`<?php  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';`

This is the result,

```
Array
(
    [id] => 11111111111
    [first_name] => Dick
    [last_name] => Peters
    [tagged_places] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1111111111111
                            [created_time] => 1905-01-01T08:00:00+0000
                            [place] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 111111111
                                    [location] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [latitude] => 36.1313
                                            [longitude] => -95.9373
                                        )

                                    [name] => Tulsa, Oklahoma
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1111111
                            [created_time] => 2014-05-30T21:41:11+0000
                            [place] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 111111111
                                    [location] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [city] => Okmulgee
                                            [country] => United States
                                            [latitude] => 35.623012460758
                                            [longitude] => -95.972782756346
                                            [state] => OK
                                            [street] => 104 S Morton Ave
                                            [zip] => 74447-5022
                                        )

                                    [name] => Ike's Downtown Pub & Eatery
                                )

                        )
```

I have tried these things,

`$graphObject['data'][0]->id`

This error is displayed,

`Notice: Undefined index: data Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

I tried

```
foreach ($graphObject->data as $data) {
    echo $data->id
}
```

These errors displayed

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

and

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

I tried

```
$info = json_decode($graphObject,true);
   foreach ($info->data as $data) {
        echo $data->id;
    }
```

These errors displayed

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in 

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
```

Also for the sake of getting this solved and helping anyone else who has been having problems putting together an app with the FB API...

Here is my full code,

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// PDO connection class
require_once( 'actions/connection.php' );

// include required classes from Facebook SDK
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

// Called class with namespace
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '','secretStuff Here' );

 // login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.Domain.com' );


// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }

} else {
  // no session exists

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  }

}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

  // graph api request for user data with response           
$graphObject = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,tagged_places' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

be careful, `data` is a property of the array member with index `tagged_places` so you have to use 
 `$graphObject['tagged_places']->data[0]->id;` instead.

Comment: OMG! Thank you sooo soo soo so so much. Ill accept as soon as it allows me